# I want to Display User details on button click in react

Tags: reactjs

This is my table.js page

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import Reactable from 'reactable'

var Table = Reactable.Table;
var Thead = Reactable.Thead;
var Th = Reactable.Th;

export class Users extends Component {
    state = {
        pgNo: 0,
        users: [],
        isFetching:true
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(res => {
                this.setState({users: res,isFetching:false});
            });
    }

    render() {
        return this.state.isFetching
            ? (
                <div class="loader" style={{marginLeft: "50%" }}>
                    <img src="/assets/index.svg"/>
                </div>
            )
            : (
                <div className="col-sm-10">

                    <Table
                        className="table"
                        style={{
                        marginLeft: "20%",
                        marginRight: "5%"
                    }}
                        filterable={["id", "name", "username", "email", "website"]}
                        noDataText="No matching records found"
                        itemsPerPage={7}
                        currentPage={this.state.pgNo}
                        sortable={true}
                        data={this.state.users}>
                        <Thead>
                            <Th column="id">ID</Th>
                            <Th column="name">Name</Th>
                            <Th column="username">Username</Th>
                            <Th column="email">Email address</Th>
                            <Th column="website">Website</Th>
                        </Thead>
                    </Table>
                </div>
            );
    }
}
```

This is my index.js page

```
import React from 'react'
import {render} from 'react-dom'
import {Menu} from './components/header'
import {Side} from './components/sidebar'
import {MainMenu} from './components/main'
import {ControlBar} from './components/sidebar2'
import {Users} from './components/table'

window.React = React;

render(<div>
    <Menu/><Side/><ControlBar/><MainMenu/>
    <Users/>
</div>, document.getElementById('react-container'))
```

I want to create a new column that contains a button off see details.

when someone clicks that button I want to display  all the user details in it but it should only change the body of the web page and keep my header, navbar and footer the way it is

I am new to react and I am doing a project.

All the help is appreciated and feel free to point out any mistakes I made in this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code, I assume your `<Users />` component will render the user data in a table.

And you want to toggle the display state of this table.

So, what you can do is -

1. Define a state, `isTableEnabled` and set it to `false` by default in the constructor.
2. Toggle this state `onClick` of a button - `this.setState({isTableEnabled: !this.state.isTableEnabled})`
3. Attach a condition to the rendering of the table like `{this.state.isTableEnabled && <Table>...</Table>}`
4. Map `state.users` object to fill out your data rows in the table.

Hope this answers :)

**EDIT**

Here's a snippet. Your code should look more or less like this -

```
    handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({
        isTableEnabled: !this.state.isTableEnabled
    })
}
render() {
    return (
        <button onClick={this.handleClick} >Click here</button>
        {this.state.isTableEnabled && this.state.users &&
         <Table>....
         {this.state.users.map((result)=> {
             return (
                 <Tr><Td column="name">{result.something}</Td></Tr>
                );
            })}
        </Table>}
    );
}
```

Comment: you already have the data when you did componentDidMount. you just need to switch the display state

Comment: how c an i do that?

Comment: i am new to react so its hard. can you rewrite the code.

Comment: updated the answer. however, i feel you should try things yourself